# How to index 2 buttons with same selector in testcafe

Tags: javascript, java, testing, automation, testcafe

I have 2 buttons with the following selector. How can i index them in testcafe automation?

.ng-filter-widget-row > span.ng-filter-widget-column.field-col.form-group.center-block > span > button

Comment: and what exactly do you mean by indexing them ?

Comment: How can I access the button individually one after another?

Comment: You want to access them Via Selector api of automation ?

Comment: yes something like this.   this.Selector(`.ng-filter-widget-row > span.ng-filter-widget-column.field-col.form-group.center-block > span > button`); //selects the 1st button. How can I select the second button which has the same selector

Comment: does `nth` function works for you ?

Comment: https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/selectors/functional-style-selectors.html#nth

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Selector` Api offers a `nth` function you can select the item by index.

https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/selectors/functional-style-selectors.html#nth

```js
//first button
Selector(".ng-filter-widget-row > span.ng-filter-widget-column.field-col.form-group.center-block > span > button").nth(1);

// second button
Selector(".ng-filter-widget-row > span.ng-filter-widget-column.field-col.form-group.center-block > span > button").nth(2);
```